# Error while loading Custom UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, uwp

I've created a custom button for my app, in the content it has a `Textblock` and a `SymbolIcon`, both placed into a `Grid`.
This is the very simple code

```
<UserControl
    ...>

        <Grid>
            <Button Name="ButtonControl">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <SymbolIcon Grid.Column="0"
                                    Symbol="Italic"
                                    Name="SymbolIconColumn"
                                     />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text=""
                                   Name="TextBlockColumn"
                                   />
                    </Grid>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

And in its class file, I've declared a couple of properties:

1. `SymbolIcon` basically sets the `Symbol` property of the
   `SymbolIcon`
2. `Text` sets the `Text` property of the `Textblock`
3. `Click` sets the `Click` event Handler for the `Button`

This is the code behind:

```
public string Text
{
    get
    {
        return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        TextBlockColumn.Text = value;
    }
}

public Symbol SymbolIcon
{
   get
   {
       return (Symbol)GetValue(SymbolIconProperty);
   }
   set
   {
       SetValue(SymbolIconProperty, value);
   }
}


public RoutedEventHandler Click
{
    get
    {
        return (RoutedEventHandler)GetValue(ClickProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ClickProperty, value);
        ButtonControl.Click += value;
    }
}

public RoutedEventHandler Click
{
    get
    {
        return (RoutedEventHandler)GetValue(ClickProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ClickProperty, value);
        ButtonControl.Click += value;
    }
}
```

I've registered all of the them with their DependencyProperty.Register function

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SymbolIconProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SymbolIcon", typeof(Symbol), 
                typeof(TimerButton), new PropertyMetadata(Symbol.Italic));

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string),
                typeof(TimerButton), new PropertyMetadata(""));

public static readonly DependencyProperty ClickProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Click", typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
                typeof(TimerButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

I think I've done everything, right?
So, if I add the namespace into my page and try the load it, like this

```
<Page
    ...
    xmlns:bt="using:MyProject.Resources"...>

<bt:TimerButton
                SymbolIcon="Accept"
                Text="Accept"
                />
```

the designer won't even load, and it gives me this

> System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException [9652] Designer process terminated unexpectedly!

Also, the Debug crashes when the page has to load.

Comment: UWP or WPF? It can't be both.

Comment: "I think I've done everything, right?" Not exactly. You should not have anything else than `SetValue` in the setter method of the CLR wrapper of a dependency property, e.g. not call `TextBlockColumn.Text = value;`. Instead, you should bind the TextBlock's Text property to the Text property of your UserControl. Same for SymbolIcon.

Comment: Thanks. It's UWP by the way, How do I bind the Text property correctly?

Comment: Assign the `x:Name` attribute at the UserControl, then bind like `Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=...}"`.

Comment: Do I have to assign the x:Name in the definition of the UserControl or in the implementation (bt:TimerButton)?
And should the bind be done in the TextBlock in the definition?

Comment: In XAML, like `<UserControl x:Name="uc" ...>`

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried this but it says  **Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component**

`<UserControl
    x:Name="uc"
    ...>
        <Grid>...
                        <SymbolIcon Grid.Column="0"
                                    Symbol="{Binding SymbolIcon,ElementName=uc}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=uc}"
                          ...
        </Grid>
</UserControl>`

Comment: Why you are creating a UserControl just to create a custom button. You can archive this with a normal button. Just create a custom style for your button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Clemens, I've corrected the code by removing the unnecessary instructions, and also the `Click` EventHandler property. 
An `EventHandler` cannot be added as a `DependencyProperty`, thus all the debug crashing and all of that exception throwing. I'm still figuring out how I'm gonna add it.

```
public string ButtonText
{
    get
    {
        return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }
}

public Symbol Icon
{
   get
   {
       return (Symbol)GetValue(SymbolIconProperty);
   }
   set
   {
       SetValue(SymbolIconProperty, value);
   }
}
```

I've also added Binding to the `TextBlock`'s `Text` and `SymbolIcon`'s `Symbol` properties. I've done this by giving a `x:Name` to the UserControl (`MyButton`) and binding the property with the string `{Binding Path=/*name of the property of the UserControl to bind*/, ElementName="MyButton"`

```
<UserControl
...
x:Name="MyButton">
....
....
<!--only showing for the TextBlock, but I've done the same for the SymbolIcon-->
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
           Text="{Binding Path=ButtonText,ElementName=MyButton}"/>
```